# Create wordcloud from dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, word-cloud

I just wrote a script that extracts all the spoken text in the Dutch Parlement of a few thousand XML files. For every speaker it count the amount of times a speaker said some words.

After doing this I calculated the TF * IDF value of every word for each speaker in the Dutch Parlement. If you are not familiar with this see this link: [TF IDF explanation](http://www.tfidf.com/)

So now I have a dictionary for each speaker in the Dutch Parlement where the keys are the words he said and the values are the corresponding TF*IDF values:

```
{u'asielzoekers': 0.0034861170591325486,
 u'belastingverlaging': 0.0018551991553514675,
 u'buma': 0.0020712555982839408,
 u'islam': 0.0029519544163739155,
 u'moslims': 0.0027958002747301355,
 u'ouderen': 0.0022803123245457566,
 u'pechtold': 0.0021525864470786928,
 u'president': 0.003281844532743345,
 u'rutte': 0.0023488684001475584,
 u'samsom': 0.0019304632325980841}
```

Right now I want to create a wordcloud from these values. I have shortly looked into the wordcloud module written by *amueller* But for as far as I can see this module is not working with a dictionary but just plain text.

So any help on how to create a wordcloud from a dictionary's values would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Following https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/207 you should be able to do `WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(MyData)` where MyData is a dict.

Comment: @fredtantini - your suggestion worked for me. You should post it as an answer and get some of that sweet sweet karma points :).

Answer (score 14):

```
dictionary= {u'asielzoekers': 0.0034861170591325486,.. u'samsom': 0.0019304632325980841} 


from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wc = WordCloud(background_color="white",width=1000,height=1000, max_words=10,relative_scaling=0.5,normalize_plurals=False).generate_from_frequencies(dictionary)
plt.imshow(wc)
```

Comment: It seems wordcloud is not available for python >= 3.7

Answer (score 4):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

word_could_dict = {'Git':100, 'GitHub':100, 'push':50, 'pull':10, 'commit':80, 'add':30, 'diff':10, 
                  'mv':5, 'log':8, 'branch':30, 'checkout':25}

wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1000, height = 500).generate_from_frequencies(word_could_dict)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```

And we get:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Creating Wordcloud with Dictionaries

### 05/02/21 | 5th of February 2021 |

Producing a visualised wordcloud image from dictionary name-value pair values with WordCloud's module method of the following: `generate()`, `generate_from_text()` and `generate_from_frequencies()`will not work after I tried so many times figuring it out how to overcome this problem.

Having checked on Stack Overflow if there's any way around to it, I tried replicating the solution from the above answers in my program. It did not resolve the issue I had which was a `TypeError` exception from creating & displaying a wordcloud image.

After checking the ["WordCloud API Documentation"](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/frequency.html?highlight=frequencies) from their official module site, I found out you have to manually use something called "multidict". It's a Python module which acts like a dictionary utilising..

> "[a] collection of key-value pairs where key might be occurred more than
> once in the container"

**-* quoted from the [Multidict's main PyPi introductory page](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/)*

- For more information on Multidict's module, click here: https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- To check out their official GitHub repositiory, click the following: https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict

Extracted from *"WordCloud's Gallery of Example"* page, here is a snippet of using the `multidict` module to build a **frequency dictionary** of values visualised in a **wordcloud** display:

```
import multidict as multidict
...

def getFrequencyDictForText(sentence):
    
    # instantiate multidict object
    fullTermsDict = multidict.MultiDict()
    tmpDict = {}

    # making dict for counting frequencies
    for text in sentence.split(" "):
        ...
        val = tmpDict.get(text, 0)
        tmpDict[text.lower()] = val + 1
    
    for key in tmpDict:
        fullTermsDict.add(key, tmpDict[key])
    
    return fullTermsDict


def makeImage(text):
    alice_mask = np.array(Image.open("alice_mask.png"))
    
    # instantiate and define wordcloud properties 
    wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=1000, mask=alice_mask)
    
    # generate wordcloud
    wc.generate_from_frequencies(text)

    # display and show "wc"
    plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
    plt.show()

...
...
```

Note: This is not the full source. To see the whole code, check out [Amueller WordCloud website](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/frequency.html?highlight=frequencies)